# What do you need for the CDI capability in a JSF Project?

Tags: java, jsf-2, websphere, java-ee-6, cdi

I have a JSF project targeted on WebSphere Application Server 8 and I tried to use the CDI concept. I have a `/WEB-INF/beans.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee " title="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">" class="link">http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd"> (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd)
</beans>
```

Here is my managed bean:

```
@ConversationScoped
@Named("systemParameter")
public class SystemParameter implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private ConfigFacade parameterFacade;
```

Here is a snippet from the Xhtml page:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{systemParameter.doSave}"/>
```

If I try to click on button, I get the following exception.

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /systemParameters.xhtml at line 99 and column 99 action="#{systemParameter.doSave}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'systemParameter' resolved to null
```

What do I need more?

Comment: have you double checked the imports in your managed bean to make sure you are importing the CDI Annotations?

Comment: @vcetinick Yes:-) `import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;`

Comment: Java is case sensitive. `Beans.xml` is not the same as `beans.xml`. The file location also matters, but you didn't tell anything about it. The content actually doesn't matter (it can be kept empty), but you've shown some strange node value.

Comment: @BalusC The name of the file is `beans.xml`. The location is under  WEB-INF.

Comment: Fine. How about the XML syntax error in the `beans.xml` file? Try emptying the file instead of putting malformed content. Websphere might have fallen over that.

Comment: @BalusC I emptied the file. i get the same error..

Comment: Okay, that'll be Websphere specific. Sorry, that's beyond me.

Comment: @BalusC It means, everything else is correct.. Right? I mean it is expected the class to be resolved

Comment: Yes. As per the spec it's just a matter of having a `/WEB-INF/beans.xml` file present in the WAR (and of course a valid CDI implementation like Weld or OpenWebBeans in the runtime classpath, but Websphere is supposed to already provide it, otherwise it wouldn't have been a Java EE 6 compliant application server).

Comment: I googled on ["websphere cdi"](http://google.com/search?q=websphere+cdi) and got this [manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Fcweb_cdi.html) as 1st hit which says *"CDI is only supported with the default WebSphere Application Server class loader policy, Class loader for each WAR file in application, and not with the alternative, single class loader for application setting."* Have you checked it?

Comment: @BalusC I am also new in websphere world. I try to find something about this configuration

Comment: I've worked with WebSphere 5.x/6.x from 2003 to 2008. Happy that I don't work with that odd beast anymore.

Comment: @BalusC a very good decision :-)

Comment: I agree with BalusC this is probably specific for websphere and I have no suggestions :-(

@Named("systemParameter")

Could be replaced with 
@Named

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

On WAS 8.x, make sure you are using the Apache MyFaces 2.x implementation for dependency injection of EJB (as well as CDI for that matter) to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually on second thought I can at least share a snippet that might help you find out whats wrong.

Use the following

```
@PostConstruct
private void test() {
    Bean<?> bean = (Bean) manager.resolve(manager.getBeans("systemParameter"));
        System.out.println(bean);

}
```

now if the manager prints null you probably have a problem. Try debugging,

Place a breakpoint at the println and check the manager for how many beans it got. In Eclipse hover manager click on beans, check under underlying array, how big is it? Report back.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have used

```
@Inject
private ConfigFacade parameterFacade
```

instead of the `@EJB` annotation to inject the session bean into the web controller